# Spring Rest Service Transasctional behaviour

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, jta

we have developed spring REST application.. and we are consuming third party services for our business..like CRUD services...but our tracking purpose whatever transaction we do we log that transations in database.

so now the scenario is if we update some information ( create, update, delete) from the REST service through third party api's, and after we log that transaction in database and if database is down we need to rollback the transaction. now may not rollback the transaction made through third party services.

our aim is if our database is down we are not going to use the third pary api for any REST service.
 I dont need code. I just need some idea or any design specific idea.

Comment: Can't you just check if your database is down first before calling any services?

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is just to make sure that the database is "up" before making the third party call, you can do a connection check before making the third party call. E.g. you can simply execute a light sql like `select 1 from dual`; and if that was successful go ahead and make the 3rd party calls; then log them in database.

**Note**: Make sure that the transaction you open to do the connection check is closed before going to network and similarly the logging in database is done after you are done making network calls. Database session should not remain active during 3rd party calls.